# JavaScript bind arguments correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I've got the following `bootstrap3` button code which is enclosed inside a container `div`. The button has no text apart from a `plus` icon.

```
<div id="container">
    ...
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-success input-sm btn-add">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign black" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   </a>
    ...
</div>
```

Following is my `JS-Object` with event listener for the `plus` button.

```
var query_builder = {
    init: function() {
        this.cacheDom();
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    cacheDom: function() {
        this.$container = $("#container");
        ...
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        this.$container.on('click', '.btn-add', this.addRule.bind(this));
        ...
    },
    addRule: function(evt) {
        ...
        ...
        $(evt.target).addClass('invisible');
    }
}
```

- When I click anywhere outside `plus` icon but within the button, the event gets triggered and at the end it goes invisible.
- When I click exactly the `plus` icon the event gets trigged but only the icon goes invisible leaving the button blank. I don't know how to pass the context of the button correctly when I bind the event.

Note: I'm new to Object Oriented JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe try evt.currentTarget

Comment: @positlabs Worked like a charm!!! :-)

Comment: Hehe. Cool! I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `evt.currentTarget`. It's a special jQuery event field that has something to do with event delegation, I think. I wish I had a more solid answer, but I'm glad it worked for you :)

Edit: Here is some documentation.

**event.currentTarget**

https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/

> Description: The current DOM element within the event bubbling phase.
>
> This property will typically be equal to the this of the function.

**event.target**

https://api.jquery.com/event.target/

> Description: The DOM element that initiated the event.
>
> The target property can be the element that registered for the event
> or a descendant of it. It is often useful to compare event.target to
> this in order to determine if the event is being handled due to event
> bubbling. This property is very useful in event delegation, when
> events bubble.